# Which is correct: 'a fear of never doing something' or 'a fear never to do something'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, lexicon

In a story my students are currently reading, a mother who is an alcoholic and has a daughter with speech disorder does not ask the social services for help because she fears she might very well never see her daughter again.

If I use the noun 'fear' instead of the verb, is it

> the mother's fear never to see her daughter again

or

> the mother's fear of never seeing her daughter again

?

I looked up quite a few dictionaries and grammar and could not find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I don't know how to go 'research' this, but the second option seems the definite choice to me. `the mother's fear of never seeing her daughter again` . Same for the options in  title. `a fear of never doing something.` The other arrangement can only go in a sentence where fear is a verb - `the mother fears never seeing her daughter again`

Comment: The reason I asked the question was because I imagined something parallel to 'someone if afraid of doing something (accidentally)' versus 'someone is afraid to do something (intentionally, so they are hesitant), as in 'He is afraid of falling.' versus 'He is afraid to jump or dive.' said of someone on a diving board.

Comment: Neither is correct. It should be _anything_ because negative. And _fear_ takes _of_ plus gerund, not _to_ plus infinitive.